# In this trie data structure implementation the display function is not working.Why?

Tags: c

When i display I am getting different answer but search is working. It could be a semantic error.Please help to correct it. It could have an error somewhere. I don't know where is it.Please help me to find it.The insert does not work in the program.It could be an error somewhere.I need this trie data structure to work.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #define maxlength 10
    
    
    typedef struct node
    {
      int isend;
      struct node *branch[27];
    }trinode;
    
    int len,count;
    
    trinode *createnode()
    {
      trinode *new=(trinode *)malloc(sizeof(trinode));
      int ch;
      for(ch=0;ch<27;ch++)
      {
        new->branch[ch]=NULL;
      }
      new->isend=0;
      return new;
    }
    
    trinode *insert_trie(trinode *root,char *newenty)
    {int ind;
        trinode *proot;
        if(root==NULL)
           root=createnode();
        proot=root;
      for(int i=0;i<maxlength;i++)
      {
          ind=newenty[i]-'a';
          if(newenty[i]=='\0')
             break;
         else
         {
           if(root->branch[ind]==NULL)
              root->branch[ind]=createnode();
            root=root->branch[ind];
         }
      }
        if(root->isend!=0)
           printf("trying to insert duplicate");
        else   
           root->isend=1;
             
         return proot;  
    }
    
    void print_trie(trinode *cur)
    {
      int count;
     char word[40]; 
      
       for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
       {
        if(cur->branch[i]!=NULL)
        {
          word[count++]=(i+'a');
        if((cur->branch[i]->isend)==1)
        {
          printf("\n");
         
          for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
          {
            printf("%c",word[j]);
          }
        } 
        print_trie(cur->branch[i]); 
        }
      
       }
      count--; 
    }
    
    int search_trie(trinode *root,char *target)
    {
      int ind;
    for(int i=0;i<maxlength &&root;i++)
    {
      ind=target[i]-'a';
      if(target[i]=='\0')
        break;
      else
         root=root->branch[ind]; 
    }
    
    if(root && root->isend==1)
       return 1;
    else   
       return 0;
    }
    int main()
    {
    int ch;
    trinode *root=NULL;
    char *newenty;
    char *target;
    int check;
     newenty = (char *)malloc(maxlength);
     target= (char *)malloc(maxlength);
    while(1)
    {
    printf("\n enter option 1.insert_trie 2.display 3.search 4.exit");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    
    {
         case 1:
            printf("enter word");
            scanf("%s",newenty);
          root=insert_trie(root,newenty);
            break;
            
         case 2:
            count =0;
            print_trie(root);
            break;
    
           case 3:
            printf("enter elem you want to search");
            scanf("%s",target);
           check=search_trie(root,target);
           if(check==0)
              printf("word not found");
            else
              printf("found");
            break;
            
            case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;
    
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You used `count` without initializing in the function `print_trie`. This invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It seems you should start with formatting your code properly (fix indentation).

Comment: Also you should define the specification (what to print, etc.) first.